# Adjust code in arbitrary Divi module

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to change the layout of a module made with Divi. I would really like to just use PHP or HMTL to make the change, but do not see where that is an option.

I can export the existing module as JSON, but that only maps the settings as set in the builder.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to access the code of a Divi module?

Answer (score 1):

Each divi module has it's own .php file. You can override it with a child theme! Just copy the code from the module into your own file and do your changes.